# Statistics reference for measures of agreement?

Tags: references, agreement-statistics

I am looking for a statistically-oriented textbook (accessible to one who has knowledge of the material in Casella and Berger's text) which explains the theory behind measures of agreement - e.g., Coehn's $\kappa$ or Cronbach's $\alpha$. I am not at all aware of what kinds of textbooks I would expect to find this information in. My first thought was to look in a multivariate analysis text like Johnson and Wichern, but these topics are not in there.

If papers are the best resources for learning about this material, I'll stick to those, but I do wonder what references statisticians use for such material.

Comment: Is this just for self study, or to use as an adjunct for a class?  There are lightweight books, but I don't know of anything that would bring C&B to mind.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Self study.

Comment: Why have you deleted your [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531279/translating-an-experimental-design-to-lme4-syntax) ? I was trying to post an answer !

Comment: @RobertLong Sorry, I'll undelete it in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem.  Too much "magical thinking" in the applied references for these measures, and nothing to be found in the more technical references. But here is a really great one along the lines of what you need for Cronbach's Alpha.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_corr_sect019.htm

Answer (score 0):

Gwet, K. L. (2014). Handbook of inter-rater reliability: The definitive guide to measuring the extent of agreement among raters (4th ed.). Advanced Analytics.

https://agreestat.com/

Note that the author is working on a 5th edition now.